# When does EF Core LINQ query result in null coalescing despite SingleOrDefault() would return null?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query against the DbContext something like:

```
ctx.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == *someQueryThatReturns0*).Code
```

The `someQueryThatReturns0` is a query that looks up an Id, something like the following:

```
otherItems.Where(h => h.Id == xyz).Select(s => s.OtherId).SingleOrDefault()
```

When this inner query has no results, then the inner `SingleOrDefault` will return 0 because the Ids are int, and this means the outer `Items.SingleOrDefault(..)` should result in null.

But when referencing `Items.SingleOrDefault(..).Code` instead of getting NullRef exception, it will be just null.

This whole thing is part of a bigger query where it is used in to set values in a Select(), something like:

```
someComplexQuery.Select(x => new someDto(){
  ...
  someProp = x.Valid ? ctx.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == *someQueryThatReturns0*).Code : null;
  ...
})
```

When executing the query I would have expected a NullRef exception, but instead someProp is simply coalesced to `null` basically. Is this the expected behavior simply because referencing `.Code` in the query like this will be translated into the SQL query somehow?
Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
  someProp = x.Valid ? ctx.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == *someQueryThatReturns0*).Code : null;
```

This line should definitely return null at the SingleOrDefault, if Item object is a class, and therefore to throw NullReferenceException.

If it's a struct type then it would initialize the struct with all its values in turn default initialized (i.e. zero, null, etc.).

Assuming it's a class, the only way that `someProp` will be set to `null` eventually, is if Items collection has an item with Id equal to zero, and it's `Code` property is set to `null`,
or if `x.Valid` is set to `false`.